# Why is there an EOF in the middle of the arguments?

Tags: bash, python

I wanted to write a little bash function such that I can tell bash, `import os` or `from sys import stdout` and it will spawn a new Python interpreter with the module imported.

The latter `from` function looks like this:

```
from () {
    echo "from $@" | xxd
    python3 -i -c "from $@"
}
```

If I call this:

```
$ from sys import stdout
00000000: 6672 6f6d 2073 7973 2069 6d70 6f72 7420  from sys import 
00000010: 7374 646f 7574 0a                        stdout.
  File "<string>", line 1
    from sys
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

The bytes in `from sys` are

```
66 72 6f 6d 20 73 79 73 20
f  r  o  m     s  y  s
```

There's no EOF in there, yet the Python interpreter is behaving as if it read EOF. There is a newline at the end of the stream, which is to be expected.

`from`'s sister, that imports a whole Python module, looks like this, and which solves the problem by sanitising and processing the string, and by failing on non-existent modules.

```
import () {
  ARGS=$@
  ARGS=$(python3 -c "import re;print(', '.join(re.findall(r'([\w]+)[\s|,]*', '$ARGS')))")
  echo -ne '\0x04' | python3 -i
  python3 -c "import $ARGS" &> /dev/null
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "sorry, junk module in list"
  else
    echo "imported $ARGS"
    python3 -i -c "import $ARGS"
  fi
}
```

That solves the problem of an unexplained EOF in the stream, but I would like to understand why Python thinks there is an EOF.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The table in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099707/309308) (which got it from the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams)) explains how the different Bash variables are expanded:

[image]

You're doing `python -i -c "from $@"`, which turns into `python -i -c "from sys" "import" "stdout"`, and `-c` only takes a single argument, so it's running the command `from sys`. You want to use `$*`, which will expand into `python -i -c "from sys import stdout"` (assuming `$IFS` is unset or starts with a space).

Comment: Thank you for undeleting, as this is valuable information :)

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer as this actually solves the problem, the other upvoted one just explains the problem, but it doesn't give the solutions or alternative workarounds

Comment: Good answer. That table actually comes from the Bash Hackers Wiki. Could you add the proper attribution and verify that you have the right to distribute?

Answer (score 22):

`strace`, as always, will show what is going on:

```
bash-4.1$ echo $$
3458
```

And, elsewhere (or you could figure out how to `strace bash ...` the function call):

```
bash-4.1$ strace -ff -o blah -p 3458
```

And back in that first shell:

```
bash-4.1$ from sys import stdout
  File "<string>", line 1
    from sys
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 
bash-4.1$
```

And then back in the `strace` shell:

```
Process 3458 attached
Process 25224 attached
^CProcess 3458 detached
bash-4.1$ grep exec blah.*
blah.25224:execve("/usr/bin/python", ["python", "-i", "-c", "from sys", "import", "stdout"], [/* 54 vars */]) = 0
```

Thus, the actual `-c` argument is `-c "from sys"` because of how `"$@"` is expanded, or a truncated command that `python` barfs on.

Answer (score 9):

`$@` in double quotes expands to a list of elements `"$1" "$2" "$3"` etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
expand () {
    for string in "from $@" ; do
        echo "$string"
    done
}

expand sys import stdout
```

Python expects the code to be in one argument, not a series of arguments.

Answer (score 6):

Python is being invoked as

```
execve("/usr/bin/python", ["python", "-i", "-c", "from sys", "import", "stdout"], [/* 54 vars */])
```

(see [thrig's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264125/112566)).

To get `$@` expanded as a single string (assuming a sane `$IFS`), you can use `$*` inside double quotes:

```
python3 -i -c "from $*"
```

Confirmed with `strace -e execve`:

```
execve("/usr/bin/python", ["python", "-i", "-c", "from sys import stdout"], [/* 54 vars */]) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Strace do show what are the arguments used. But the simplest method to see what is being processed is to add a `printf '<%s> '` before each relevant line, and a closing `echo` (to generate as new line):

So, the function could be changed to this:

```
from () {
    printf '<%s> ' "from $@"; echo
    printf '<%s> ' python3 -i -c "from $@"; echo
}
```

And when called:

```
$ from sys import stdout
<from sys> <import> <stdout> 
<python3> <-i> <-c> <from sys> <import> <stdout>
```

It is clear that "from sys" is being sent to python as one argument.
That is what python receives, and python acts on "from sys".